# getdir in c++, to choose a saving directory

Tags: c++, getdirectories

I have a `qdialog` with a `qlineedit` where the user can write his chosen path to save a file. I would like to implement a `pushbutton` (Open) where if the user presses it, it will be something similar to `uigetdir` in `matlab`. it returns the path chosen in a string. Any suggestions in c++?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QFileDialog](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qfiledialog.html) offers the ability to select directories. Especially [getExistingDirectory](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectory) should cover your use case.

Answer (score 1):

[QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectory)